# We DO or MAKE a practice, or just practice?

Tags: do-vs-make

What's considered more natural, to **do a practice**, to **[make a practice](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+practice+of)**, or simply **practice** only without preceding words?

In fact, I've heard all of them, and I have no a way to know how to choose one of them.

Context for example:

> I need to make / do / practice English speaking.

Comment: Usually we just use the plain verb, as in *I practice [playing the] the piano on Sunday*. Alternatively, *I **have** piano practice on Sunday*. Sometimes the first version more strongly implies a "regular, habitual" activity, and the first version may more strongly imply ***I am obliged / committed** to playing* (perhaps *every* Sunday, or perhaps just *next* Sunday). The usage ***to do practice*** does exist, but it's often not very idiomatic, so you should probably avoid it. And forget about ***to make practice***.

Comment: Thank you.  So what is this? https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+practice+of

Comment: to make a practice of doing something = to make a habit of doing something. That is an idiomatic expression in English/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the verb "to practise" and the noun "practice" (note the spelling difference, but native speakers also frequently misspell these words too). So you can say

> I need to practise English speaking.

You don't normally "make practice", but you could also say

> I need to do lots of English speaking practice.

The idiom "make a practice of" means "do something regularly"  You could say "I make a practice of going to church on Sunday".  It isn't the same sense of "practice" as in "I do lots of English practice".

Comment: Spelling the verb **practise** (with an **s** rather than a **c**) appears to be a British rather than an American practice. https://www.dictionary.com/e/practice-vs-practise/